# Ubuntu One, Dashboard shows 14.5mb used and files folder shows nothing

Tags: ubuntu-one

Hope you can help.

My dashboard on ubuntu one shows that I have 14.5mb in the files tab, but under the files section, it is saying the "Lets get started with syncing your files."  I have synced and stopped syncing folders with files just to test out how it worked., but I don't think it was 14.5mb worth of files.  Is there a way to reset or clear an account?  Who would I contact about this issue?

I have tried the "How do I stop syncing a folder outside the Ubuntu One folder?" tips.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

It's likely that you are affected by this [bug](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/WhyIsMyStorageUsageReportedWrong). There is a contact address in the link.

Comment: Thank you Javier Rivera, I must have missed that bug in my readings.  At least now I know there is a problem and I am not crazy.  Thank you again.