# My Ubuntu One account is empty but I'm still using 8.7 MB?

Tags: ubuntu-one

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu One, Dashboard shows 14.5mb used and files folder shows nothing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16827/ubuntu-one-dashboard-shows-14-5mb-used-and-files-folder-shows-nothing)

My Ubuntu One account is empty but the Ubuntu One website says I'm still using 8.7 megabytes. Why is this?

Comment: Take a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16827/ubuntu-one-dashboard-shows-14-5mb-used-and-files-folder-shows-nothing

Answer (score 0):

At the uttermost right, there is a label containing "More". If you click it, then the file will be expanded like a treeview, and you'll get options to publish, download or delete the file. Also, if you login to your Ubuntu One account on your desktop, then you can delete the file in Nautilus, because deletes are also synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Ubuntu One folder in nautilus and press CTRL+H. This will probably show some hidden files/folders.